# Got - HTTPS Request - HTTPError

Tags: node.js, https, basic-authentication

I'm trying to hit a URL protected by basic auth using the snippet below.

```
const got = require('got');
export const getToken = async () => {

    const payload = new URLSearchParams({grant_type: 'client_credentials'}).toString();
    const auth = "Bearer " + Buffer.from(process.env.username + ":" + process.env.password).toString('base64');
    try{
        const response = await got(process.env.url, {
            body: payload,
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Authorization" : auth,
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Content-Length": payload.length.toString()
            }
        });
    }catch(error){
        console.log(`ERROR: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    }
    
};
```

But this results in an error and there are no specifics provided either.

```
{"name":"HTTPError","timings":{"start":1634484011218,"socket":1634484011219,"lookup":1634484011230,"connect":1634484011248,"secureConnect":1634484011288,"upload":1634484011288,"response":1634484011307,"end":1634484011310,"abort":1634484011314,"phases":{"wait":1,"dns":11,"tcp":18,"tls":40,"request":0,"firstByte":19,"download":3,"total":96}}}
```

Any advice on resolving the issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Print the error using `console.log('ERROR:', error)` (separate argument instead of concatenation, no `JSON.stringify`), then you'll see what the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

It's happening on `got`.
You need to parse the error and see what the error is. You can follow this at error.

```js
const { HTTPError } = require('got')

const parsedError = new HTTPError(err)
console.log('---err--->', parsedError.response.body)
```

You will see what the exact issue is.

Comment: The error is already an `HTTPError`...